# Is it possible that a human can survive after a chestburster came out?

Tags: alien

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_(creature_in_Alien_franchise)):

> The "Alien" (colloquial: "Xenomorph"; binomial: *Internecivus
>   raptus ["murderous thief"]*) is a fictional endoparasitoid
>   extraterrestrial species that is the eponymous antagonist of the *Alien*
>   film series. The species made its debut in the film *Alien* (1979), and
>   reappeared in the sequels *Aliens* (1986), *Alien 3* (1992), and *Alien
>   Resurrection* (1997), as well as the crossover films *Alien vs. Predator*
>   (2004) and *Aliens vs. Predator: Requiem* (2007).

These Aliens' life life stages are 1. Ovomorph or Egg, 2. Facehugger, 3. Chestburster 4. Xenomorph XX121.

These alien creatures begin their lives as an egg, which hatches a parasitic larval form known as a facehugger, which then attaches itself to a living host by latching onto its face. Most of the movies' facehuggers used humans as their living host. After that, chestbusters come out from the human’s chest.

Is it possible that a human can survive after a chestbuster came out? Is there anything mentioned about a character that survived after a chestbuster came out from the above-mentioned movies?

Comment: Consider the physiology that's portrayed; could you imagine anyone surviving that?

Comment: Considering anyone would survive the birth of the chestbuster, he would not live long when the little guy gets hungry...

Comment: Can you precise came out ?  
In Promotheus, Elisabeth Show is able to surgically remove the proto-alien and surviving. Even if we are not talking exactly the same specie, it would make sense that a surgical removing of a chestbuster to be possible (but could a human surgeon survive the removal, that's another question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it bursts out of their chest. Humans cannot survive if something bursts out of their  chest considering that Humans need a heart, lungs, and stomach to survive, and when the Alien bursts out out of their chest, that is exactly what they rip apart and destroy.

The only way I could think that a human would survive that is if they got cybernetic replacements for the destroyed parts, but they would need to be right next to a hospital with someone able to operate instantly and quickly finish the operation, that is if they even survive the shock of an alien bursting out of their chest, and survive the trip to the hospital.

TL;DR: No, without immediately having access to replacement parts and a skilled surgeon, Humans will not survive an Xenomorph bursting out of their chest.

Answer (score 2):

I've thought about this. Let's say it's just in the cavity space. So all it does is break the rib cage. That alone would be such a shock to the body you would have to be put under as soon as it happens. Second, the body is being used for resources, the alien is feeding off the host. So by the time you get to that last stage the body is weakened. In the first movie he was sedated and sleeping. But in other movies the host he wake and was drained. (This one is alive... Please kill me) Good question!